# show a Collection of LineStrings with labels

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling, linestring

I use the following peace of code to show multiple `LineString`s which have a point as the last one, along with a label:

```js
var strokeColors = [...];//"#FFAACC" kind-of elements
var linesLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Lines Layer", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
        pointRadius: 6,
        labelYOffset: -15,
        labelOutlineColor: "white",
        labelOutlineWidth: 3,
        label: "${label}"
    }})
});
var feats = [];
for(var j=0;j<lines.length;j++){
    var points = [];
    var feat;
    for(var i=0;i<lines[j].length;i++){
        var p = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lines[j][i].x,lines[j][i].y);
        if(i==lines[j].length-1){
            feat = p;
        }
        points.push(p);
    }
    var lineString = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
    var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection([lineString, feat]));
    lineFeature.style = {
        strokeColor: strokeColors[j%4],
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWidth: 6
    };
    lineFeature.attributes = {
        label: lines[j].lab
    };
    feats.push(lineFeature);
}
linesLayer.addFeatures(feats);
map.addLayer(linesLayer);
```

This shows the lines, with the correct color for each one although the label is not shown.
Such label, though, is indeed shown if I comment out the `lineFeature.style={...}` lines. In this case, though, the lines are all black.
I'm quite new at OpenLayers, so I'm not sure: what am I doing wrong?

For reference, I started out with [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I believe you are designating a style on each loop pass which then does not use the default render intent on the stylemap. Before you do a `lineFeature.style = ...`, Try extending the default style in your stylemap and apply it to the feature instead of telling the feature to use a style which does not have any label info on it.</strike>

## Update

remove the `lineFeature.style = ...`

add the color value to your feature attributes:

```js
lineFeature.attributes = {
    label: 'lalal',
    color: strokeColors[j%4]
};
```

and replace this for your linesLayer constructor:

```js
var linesLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Lines Layer", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
        pointRadius: 6,
        labelYOffset: -15,
        labelOutlineColor: "white",
        labelOutlineWidth: 3,
        label: "${label}",
        strokeColor: "${color}",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWidth: 6
    }})
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion, but the result is the same: colored line, but no point nor label.

Comment: Do you have the values of the lines array so I can test it?

Comment: they're retrieved from a webservice. gimme a few mins and i'll try to set up a fiddle

Comment: Or if you could just paste in the resulting JSON of the webservice, that would work, if possible.

Comment: it's actually a massive xml, cause it was built for something else. (which is source of other pains, but nevermind)

Comment: mmm, not sure how to make fiddle work.. :( anyway, here's the data, should be right: lines=[[{x="0.765695",y="44.777461"},{x="0.764352",y="44.776795"},{x="0.764203",y="44.776459"},{x="0.764295",y="44.775936"},{x="0.765557",y="44.772885"},{x="0.765728",y="44.772613"},{x="0.766352",y="44.771627"},{x="0.767672",y="44.768821"},{x="0.767738",y="44.768021"},{x="0.767823",y="44.766453"}]];

Comment: no worries... that's good.

Comment: @Stephan Check my update.